# How to configure GWT debugging with docker?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, gwt, docker

I have my GWT project deploying in the docker containers. Tomcat application server container requires `my_project.war`, so every time I make a change in the code, I have to rebuild my project, replace old .war with the new one, rebuild container and run it again. This appears to be very ineffective and frustrating. My question is: How can I debug this in any easier way?

Comment: debugging client or server code ? You can mount a volume into the docker and deploy an exploded war folder.

Comment: I was searching internet finding a sample...I don't found anything.

Comment: Actually I found a solution. There is built-in gwt run configuration in Ultimate Intellij IDEA15 where I set all needed ports from docker containers. Don't know how to do it with another IDEs.

Comment: @Praytic I am trying to do this, how did you set/attached the needed ports

Comment: may i ask how did you dockerize your gwt application ?